# Exception with Linq2SQL Query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am running a query using Linq2SQL that comes down to following query:

```
DateTime? expiration = GetExpirationDate();
IQueryable<Persons> persons = GetPersons();
IQueryable<Items> subquery = from i in db.Items
                             where i.ExpirationDate >= expiration
                             select i;

return persons.Where(p => p.Items != null && p.Items.Any(item => subquery.Contains(item)));
```

When I evaluate the result of the function, I get a NullReferenceException and here's the stack trace. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?!

Basically I want to select all the persons and filter them by item expiration date.

```
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.Member(SqlExpression expr, MemberInfo member)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression ma)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitContains(Expression sequence, Expression value)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitQuantifier(SqlSelect select, LambdaExpression lambda, Boolean isAny)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Comment: You might need to post the code for GetPersons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if expiration is null, it's still not a null reference (hint: reference).

Hadi, the problem is you wrote clever code. Instead write debug-able code.

Answer (score 0):

Is `expiration` null? Maybe there's the problem.